# Emacs Lisp function to toggle variable 'tab-width' between 4 & 8

Tags: emacs

The source tree that I work on has files indented with different tab values, (not to mention spaces) and the best I can do is to set emacs to use the style found in the region of code I am modifying. Instead of doing M-x set-variable tab-width to 4 or 8, a key binding to toggle the tab-width among these two value would help immensely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
;; Obviously substitute your preferred key for <f8>
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'tf-toggle-tab-width-setting) ; ' "fix" highlighting

(defun tf-toggle-tab-width-setting ()
    "Toggle setting tab widths between 4 and 8"
    (interactive)
    (setq tab-width (if (= tab-width 8) 4 8))
    (redraw-display))
```

*Edited to add redraw-display as per comment suggested*

Comment: Thanks. I added a redraw-display after setting the variable so that the change is reflected immediately.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of hitting f8 each time I open a buffer, can I add something to my .emacs to run this automatically?

Comment: @IanCohen I'm not quite sure what you want.  The request was for toggling the width.  If you want it to be set to a particular value for all buffers, add `(setq-default tab-width 4)` (or whatever value you want).

Comment: I ended up using M-x untabify after toggling tab-width 4. Adding (setq-default tab-width 4) to my .emacs didn't change the spacing of files which had tab-width 8. Using the toggle function above changed the spacing, but I had to run it each time I opened a buffer. Thanks for following up.

Comment: Tip: You can toggle between 8, 4 or 2 with this line instead:

`(setq tab-width (if (= tab-width 8) 4 (if (= tab-width 4) 2 8)))`

Answer (score 5):

Not quite answering the question (the answers given are good enough), but you might want to consider setting a per-file local variable. For example, assuming that "//" means comment in your language, you would put the following in the *first* line of the file:

```
// -*- tab-width: 4 -*-
```

And emacs will set the variable for you whenever you visit the file. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html for more information on file-based variables.

Of course this might not be a choice if the file is shared among a group - unless you can convince your colleges that this first line comment is completely harmless and *extremely* useful!

Comment: Thanks. We have editor specific markup in some files, but it's generally frowned upon as everyone uses a different editor :-/

Comment: And I guess it'd be a good idea to use setq-default so that a local buffer variable takes precedence. I hadn't thought about it when I put in the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers. I added a redraw-display call so that the change is reflected immediately. (Tried posting this as a comment, but can't.)

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'tf-toggle-tab-width-setting)
(defun tf-toggle-tab-width-setting ()    "toggle setting tab widths between 4 and 8"
    (interactive)
    (setq tab-width (if (= tab-width 8) 4 8))
    (message "set tab-width to %d." tab-width)
    (redraw-display)
)
```

And along the same lines. :(

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'tf-toggle-indent-mode-setting)
(defun tf-toggle-indent-mode-setting ()
    "toggle indenting modes"
    (interactive)
    (setq indent-tabs-mode (if (eq indent-tabs-mode t) nil t))
    (message "Indenting using %s." (if (eq indent-tabs-mode t) "tabs" "spaces"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw this in your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
(defun toggle-spaces ()
  "Toggle tab-width between 4 and 8"
  (interactive)
  (if (eq tab-width 4)
      (setq tab-width 8)
    (setq tab-width 4)))

;; This will set Ctrl-g to toggle but you can set it to anything
;; you want.
(global-set-key "\C-g" 'toggle-spaces)
```

Comment: C-g is hard-coded to mean "quit" in so many places that I would
recommend against rebinding that key anywhere.  It just won't work right.