# Emacs: set and toggle show-trailing-whitespace

Tags: emacs

Two related questions using emacs 23.3.1 on linux:

First, why can't I set the value of `show-trailing-whitespace` to `t` with `setq` as shown below?  When I put the `setq` version in my `.emacs` it does not change the value (as seen functionally and by using `M-x describe-variable`).

```
(setq show-trailing-whitespace t)  ; Does not change variable value or give error

(custom-set-variables              ; Sets show-trailing-whitespace as expected
 '(show-trailing-whitespace t))
```

Second, how can I toggle the value between `t` and `nil`?  I thought that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530461/emacs-lisp-function-to-toggle-variable-tab-width-between-4-8) was exactly what I needed, but it doesn't work in this case.  I used:

```
(global-set-key "\M-ow" 'tf-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace)

(defun tf-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace ()
    "Toggle show-trailing-whitespace between t and nil"
    (interactive)
    (setq show-trailing-whitespace (if (= show-trailing-whitespace nil) t nil))
    (redraw-display))
```

When I hit `M-ow` I get an error `Wront type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First: as the `describe-variable` tells you `show-trailing-whitespace` is a buffer variable. This means that doing a `setq` only sets it for the current buffer and therefore has no effect when done in the `.emacs` file. To have something similar to what custom do you need to use `setq-default` instead of `setq`. This will work for all the buffers.

Second: For toggling you might want to use `setq` if you want to toggle on a buffer per buffer basis. The error you get is that you use `=` which is to test if two numbers are equal. A toggling is done in a cleaner fashion by using `not`. As a side note, the `(redraw-display)` command does not seem to be doing anything.

```
(defun tf-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace ()
  "Toggle show-trailing-whitespace between t and nil"
  (interactive)
  (setq show-trailing-whitespace (not show-trailing-whitespace)))
```

Comment: Super, thanks!  The only caveat is that the `(redraw-display)` **does** do something useful in my case.  If some trailing whitespace is being shown in red and I toggle the setting off, without `(redraw-display)` the highlighted whitespace doesn't turn white until I manually refresh the screen.

Answer (score 0):

write (eq show-trailing-whitespace nil)

or shorter  --but reversed--

(if show-trailing-whitespace

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here from the future (Emacs 28+): One can set the variable globally with `M-x customize-variable` followed by `show-trailing-whitespace`, return, and toggling to `on`.